# How high are the monster levels on Inferno difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

The effectiveness of armor and resistances depends on the level of the monster that is causing damage to the hero. According to [one post on the Diablo III forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149150485), the formula for armor is

> DR from Armor = Armor / (Armor+(50*mLvl))

Now, I would assume that for most of the game the monsters are close in level to the player, at least while the player is still gaining levels. But how do the monster levels far on Inferno difficulty? The player is fixed at level 60 there, are the monsters also fixed to this level or does their level increase further in higher acts?

The reason I'm interested in this specifically is that a further increasing monster level would make armor and resistances less effective compared to just increasing the HP by stacking vitality. Knowing the approximate monster level is necessary to calculate whether adding more HP or more armor/resistances is more effective at a specific point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inferno is only for level 60 characters. Therefore the monsters need to be much tougher.

EDIT: Ok I have found a [bluepost](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4254464832?page=12#227) by Bashiok:

> Previously, Inferno difficulty was mlvl 61 across all of Inferno, and now it starts at mlvl 61 and ramps up quickly in Act I and ends somewhere around 65 (?) in Act IV. We've only increased the difficulty.

If you are interested in the subject and want more details I'd also suggest his previous [bluepost](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4254459132?page=33#654) where he compares the difficulty of d3 with d2 and gives some insight into how they intended/patched the difficulties.

Have fun in Inferno ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust that wiki on those numbers, an increase of 1-3 levels wouldn't really change much.

Comment: Glad you didn't trust that wiki. You were right! Hope this is what you are looking for :D

Comment: I'm still a bit wondering about that small increase in mlvl, but you found an authorative source, so this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think the reason why the developers prefer adding hp rather than hard armorbuffs and damagereduction is because the player wants to see his damage increase. You still feel like you are making progress this way even though diablo has 10x his/her hp...